# How to merge multiple foreach into 1 foreach and sort by date

Tags: wp-query

How to combine multiple foreach in only 1 foreach and than sort the foreach based on date?

I am having a WP query based on a custom post type I created called mm_agenda. I know I can create 2 arrays (in both foreach) and than array_merge them, but in that case I only merge the dates and  foreach at the end (just) the dates. And my other information/data is gone. How to approach this?

I made the example code a bit shorter, just to be clear.
Example code:

```php
<? $agenda_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'mm_agenda',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'meta_key' => 'agenda_startdate',
                'order' => 'ASC',
            ));
            if ($agenda_query->have_posts()):?>
                <? while ($agenda_query->have_posts()) : $agenda_query->the_post();?>

                    <? foreach($events_foreach_1 as $event_foreach_1):?>
                        <? $agenda_startdate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'agenda_startdate', true );?>
                        <div class="date"><?= $agenda_startdate;?></div>
                        <div class="title"><? the_title();?></div>
                        <? // And much more data to display, based on the event ?>
                    <? endforeach;?>

                    <? foreach($events_foreach_2 as $event_foreach_2):?>
                        <? $agenda_startdate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'agenda_startdate', true );?>
                        <div class="date"><?= $agenda_startdate;?></div>
                        <div class="title"><? the_title();?></div>
                        <? // And much more data to display, based on the event ?>
                    <? endforeach;?>

                <? endwhile;?>
            <? endif;?>
```

**Foreach 1 outputs the following:**
2021-10-07
Name of event 1

2021-11-08
Name of event 2

**Foreach 2 output the following:**
2021-09-29
Name of event 3

2021-11-30
Name of event 4

How to collect all that information in 1 foreach or array.. And order it by the startdate. So that there will be 1 list, nicely sorted by startdate. So:

2021-09-29
Name of event 3

2021-10-07
Name of event 1

2021-11-08
Name of event 2

2021-11-30
Name of event 4

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused, your `foreach` is operating on variables that don't exist, is code missing from your question? `$events_foreach_1` and `$events_foreach_2` are pulled out of thin air. Also using `<?php` not `<?`, `<?` is used in XML and it has issues with newer versions of PHP

Comment: You are totally right Tom. My original code is much more bigger than this example, but I made it way more compact, because the main question stays the same. The events_foreach_1 and events_foreach_2 are just made up vars. It's about the output within the foreach. I want to grab that information together.

Comment: ok it's just that the structure of those variables is important, it's not clear what they contain, where they come from, e.g. do they change with each post? Lots of missing information. Be helpfully verbose, not unhelpfully concise, share the limited version to demonstrate the point but also share the longer version for context